# Can't Get Spinning Cube To Render In OpenGL

Tags: c, opengl, glfw, glm-math, glad

I'm trying to get a spinning 3D cube but I can't get it to render. There's no error, but it's just a black screen. Also, there's no checking whether the Fragment shader is working but I can assure you it is I just don't have it included here.

Here's what my code looks like:

```c
#include <glad/glad.h>
#define GLFW_INCLUDE_NONE
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

#include <cglm/cglm.h>
#include <cglm/mat4.h>
#include <cglm/vec3.h>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

float vertices[] = {
    -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
    0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
    0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
    0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
    -0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
    -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f,

    -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
    0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
    0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
    0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
    -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
    -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f,

    -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
    -0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
    -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
    -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
    -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
    -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f, 0.0f,

    0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
    0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
    0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
    0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
    0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
    0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f, 0.0f,

    -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
    0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
    0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
    0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
    -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
    -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f,

    -0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
    0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
    0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
    0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
    -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
    -0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f};

GLuint elements[] = {
    0, 1, 2,
    2, 3, 0};

static const char *vertex_shader_text =
    "#version 330 core\n"
    "layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;\n"
    "layout (location = 1) in vec2 aTexCoord;\n"
    "out vec2 TexCoord;\n"
    "uniform mat4 model;\n"
    "uniform mat4 view;\n"
    "uniform mat4 projection;\n"

    "void main()\n"
    "{\n"
    "   gl_Position = projection * view * model * vec4(aPos, 1.0f);\n"
    "   TexCoord = vec2(aTexCoord.x, aTexCoord.y);\n"
    "}";

static const char *fragment_shader_text =
    "#version 330 core\n"
    "varying vec3 color;\n"
    "void main()\n"
    "{\n"
    "    gl_FragColor = vec4(color, 1.0);\n"
    "}\n";

static void error_callback(int error, const char *description) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: %s\n", description);
}

static void key_callback(GLFWwindow *window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods) {
    if (key == GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE && action == GLFW_PRESS)
        glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, GLFW_TRUE);
}

int main(void) {
    GLFWwindow *window;
    GLuint vbo, vertex_shader, fragment_shader, program;
    GLint mvp_location, vpos_location, vcol_location;

    glfwSetErrorCallback(error_callback);

    if (!glfwInit())
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);

    window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "Simple example", NULL, NULL);
    if (!window) {
        glfwTerminate();
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    glfwSetKeyCallback(window, key_callback);

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    if (!gladLoadGLLoader((GLADloadproc)glfwGetProcAddress)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could Not Load GLFW\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    glfwSwapInterval(1);

    unsigned int VBO, VAO;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
    glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);

    glBindVertexArray(VAO);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    // position attribute
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5 * sizeof(float), (void *)0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    // texture coord attribute
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5 * sizeof(float), (void *)(3 * sizeof(float)));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);


    vertex_shader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(vertex_shader, 1, &vertex_shader_text, NULL);
    glCompileShader(vertex_shader);

    fragment_shader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(fragment_shader, 1, &fragment_shader_text, NULL);
    glCompileShader(fragment_shader);

    GLint status;
    glGetShaderiv(vertex_shader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &status);
    if(!status){
        char buffer[512];
        glGetShaderInfoLog(vertex_shader, 512, NULL, buffer);
        puts(buffer);
    }

    program = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(program, vertex_shader);
    glAttachShader(program, fragment_shader);
    glLinkProgram(program);

    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
        float ratio;
        int width, height;

        glfwGetFramebufferSize(window, &width, &height);
        ratio = width / (float)height;

        glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);


        mat4 model = {{1.f, 1.f, 1.f, 1.f}, {1.f, 1.f, 1.f, 1.f}, {1.f, 1.f, 1.f, 1.f}, {1.f, 1.f, 1.f, 1.f}};
        mat4 view = {{1.f, 1.f, 1.f, 1.f}, {1.f, 1.f, 1.f, 1.f}, {1.f, 1.f, 1.f, 1.f}, {1.f, 1.f, 1.f, 1.f}};
        mat4 projection = {{1.f, 1.f, 1.f, 1.f}, {1.f, 1.f, 1.f, 1.f}, {1.f, 1.f, 1.f, 1.f}, {1.f, 1.f, 1.f, 1.f}};

        vec3 axis = {0.5f, 1.0f, 0.0f};
        vec3 dist = {0.0f, 0.0f, -3.0f};

        glm_rotate(model, glfwGetTime(), axis);
        glm_translate(view, dist);
        glm_perspective(0.79, width / height, 0.1f, 100.0f, projection);

        unsigned int modelLoc = glGetUniformLocation(program, "model");
        unsigned int viewLoc = glGetUniformLocation(program, "view");

        glUniformMatrix4fv(modelLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, (const GLfloat *)model);
        glUniformMatrix4fv(viewLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, (const GLfloat *)view);

        unsigned int projectionLoc = glGetUniformLocation(program, "projection");
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);

        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    glfwDestroyWindow(window);

    glfwTerminate();
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: Where's your `glUniformMatrix4fv()` call for `projection`?  Also, what's up with those matrix initial values?  You usually want the [identity matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_matrix), not all-ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to initialize the matrices with the [Identity matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_matrix):

```c
mat4 model = {
    {1.f, 0.f, 0.f, 0.f}, 
    {0.f, 1.f, 0.f, 0.f},
    {0.f, 0.f, 1.f, 0.f},
    {0.f, 0.f, 0.f, 1.f}};
```

Also do so for `view` and `projection`.

The data types for the arguments of `glm_rotate` and `glm_perspective` must be `float`:

```c
glm_rotate(model, (float)glfwGetTime(), axis);
glm_translate(view, dist);
glm_perspective((float)0.79, (float)width / (float)height, 0.1f, 100.0f, projection);
```

You also forgot to create the [Index buffer](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Index_buffers):

```c
glBindVertexArray(VAO);

// [...]

unsigned int IBO;
glGenBuffers(1, &IBO);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, IBO);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(elements), elements, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

to install the program:

```c
glUseProgram(program);
```

to set the `projection` matrix uniform.

```c
unsigned int projectionLoc = glGetUniformLocation(program, "projection");
glUniformMatrix4fv(projectionLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, (const GLfloat *)projection);
```

Finally you must change the fragment shader. For example:

```c
#version 330 core
in vec2 TexCoord;
void main()
{                            
    gl_FragColor = vec4(TexCoord.xy, 0.5, 1.0);
};
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. After I submitted this I realized some of the problems (specifically glUseProgram and the frag shader) but the other's I couldn't debug.